# HTML5 SSE and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, push

I've previously used html5 eventsource for receiving data from a server (precisely, from a jsp page). I'm currently looking into rails and as I get to understand, we need to run a separate server using a gem like faye alongside webrick to get the same thing done in rails. Is that really so? Can't I simply make my eventsource listen to a rails URL? 
Thank you.
Edit: rails 3. :)

Answer (score 2):

**ActionController::Live::SSE**

You can listen to whatever endpoint you want in Rails - the difference will be that you'll have to use [ActionController::Live::SSE](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live/SSE.html)

This will need to be invoked when you send your request, to which your front-end will be able to capture any of the responses it will provide. Admittedly, I have not implemented this using a "native" setup before (we've only used [`pusher`](http://pusher.com) in production)

However, you may be able to gain benefit from [this tutorial](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html) or [this gist](https://gist.github.com/siddharthbhagwan/8801680):

```
#config/routes.rb
get "test" => "tests#test"

#app/controllers/tests_controller.rb
class TestsController < ApplicationController
   include ActionController::Live

   def test
     response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
     sse = SSE.new(response.stream, retry: 300, event: "event-name")
     sse.write({ name: 'Test'})
   ensure
     sse.close
   end

end
```

This will allow you to receive the data from the following:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var source = new EventSource("/test");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
    alert(event.data);
};
```

--

As to further intricacies of the implementation, I don't have any right now. If you'd like me to write up about `Pusher`, I will gladly do so if you leave a comment (it's far most scalable & robust)

Comment: I didnt know ActionController::Live is available in "Rails 3"

Comment: Oh sorry - it's not! My bad :( do you want me to remove the answer ?

Comment: Well, I resolved it using em-websockets. As it turns out, with `thin` running on a different port, its so damn easy to maintain a list of websocket clients and send bi-directional msgs. Anyways, thanks Rich for your efforts